# GoogleCobal (Free Version) - Working with PySpark with Hive

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hive

---

AnalysisException                         Traceback (most recent call last)

in 
----> 1 spark.sql('''CREATE TABLE employees (
2     employee_id INT,
3     employee_first_name STRING,
4     employee_last_name STRING,
5     employee_salary FLOAT,

2 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
194                 # Hide where the exception came from that shows a non-Pythonic
195                 # JVM exception message.
--> 196                 raise converted from None
197             else:
198                 raise

AnalysisException: Hive support is required to CREATE Hive TABLE (AS SELECT);
'CreateTable `pyspark_semistructureddata`.`employees`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, ErrorIfExists

`

Comment: did you pass .`enableHiveSupport()` while creating your spark session?

Comment: also make sure to add hive-site.xml in spark config